# Overriding JSF component methods with jQuery

Tags: jquery, jsf, jsf-2, primefaces

I want to override `onblur()` and `onfocus()` methods of *p:inputText* (commentInput) component with using jQuery. But I'm struggling about getting the fixed Html ID of this component I guess. I tried so far:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
     $(document.getElementById("[#{p:component('commentInput')}]")).onblur(function() {
        $(this).css({'background-color':'#DFD8D1'});
     });
});
```

Or:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
     $("[id='#{p:component('commentInput')}']").onblur(function() {
        $(this).css({'background-color':'#DFD8D1'});
         });
});
```

Both giving the same result: `Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'onblur'`.

Xhtml code is similar to this:

```
<h:form id="dtForm">
<p:outputPanel id="dataTablePanel">
    <p:dataTable id="dataTable">
        <p:column id="column">
            <p:panel>
                <p:inputText id="commentInput">
                </p:inputText>
            </p:panel>
        </p:column>
    </p:dataTable>
</p:outputPanel>
</h:form>
```

I am having one more issue about *inputText* component when I am using it with:

```
<p:inputText id="commentInput" onkeypress="if (event.keyCode == 13) {onchange(); return false;}" required="#{not empty statusBean.newComment}">
    <f:ajax event="change" listener="#{statusBean.test}" />
</p:inputText>
```

It fires the event in unexpected manner; assume that cursor is in the inputText and type sth. and click somewhere else in the page and component fires the ajax event while it's not expected to do it. I think this component is not suitable for getting a comment to a status just like in the Facebook or sth.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After hours I found the correct way, I think all other suggestions are useful for regular cases but mine was special because of the DataTable component, it was blemishing the other solutions so I found a more greedy solution to this:

```
$(window).bind("load", function() {
    var rowSize = '#{bean.numOfRows}';
    for (var i=0;i &lt; rowSize;i++)
    {
        var rowIndex=i;
        var str = 'dataTableForm' + ':dataTable:' +  rowIndex + ':commentInput';
        var element = $(document.getElementById(str));
        element.blur(function () {
           $(this).css({'box-shadow': '0 0 5px #EB2F28'});
           $(this).css({'background-color':'#DFD8D1'});
        });
     }
});
```

The first line of the function determines execution after the page load. Then I am iterating same process for all `inputText` components in the `dataTable`. `var str` has the value of fixed ID of each `inputText` components, rest of it; just CSS.

But my case even worse than this. I was doing an ajax update to determine css values and that was overrides javascript function values even it's executed page load. Execution order was like:

```
--Page Load
----Function Executes
------Ajax Call
```

To be able to execute function at the final. I changed function header to this: `function afterLoad()` and called it in the ajax updater button via this: `<p:commandLink oncomplete="afterLoad()"/>` AND BOOM IT WORKS!!!!

Answer (score 3):

There are two problems here. First is, as Anthony Grist said in his answer, that defining blur is done by `blur()` not `onblur()`. Ids in JSF contains `:` signs as id separators, so you need to escape those `:` signs. Primefaces has build in function for this, which also add `#` sign at beginning to use this in jQuery:

```
jQuery(PrimeFaces.escapeClientId("#{p:component('commentInput')}")).blur(function () {
  // your code here...
});
```

On the other hand, why to complicate, `p:inputText` has `onblur` attribute. With it you can define javascript callback to be executed. It is used as standard HTML attribute:

```
<p:inputText onblur="myFunction()"/>
```

Comment: Your code seems correct dude but not working without giving any error.

Comment: Can you inspect generated html, to see if jQuery selector is generated OK? Debugged with Firebug? Maybe Primefaces just overrides your behavior :) I also added alternative.

Comment: I've tried your second recommandation yesterday setting the onblur property means fire myFunction after any click to input text component. It's not working before the page load. And I used firebug it seems it's not entering inside the jQuery function because the section that you've write //your code here I changed here and added css changer code but debugger skips this line and goes to: }); But it returns the correct ID: dtForm:dataTable:commentInput

Answer (score 1):

The jQuery function for binding a `blur` event handler is just `.blur()`, not `.onblur()`. Additionally, in your first example, you were mixing a call to the jQuery function with a call to the native JavaScript `document.getElementById()`.

The following should work:

```
$("##{p:component('commentInput')}")).blur(function() {
    $(this).css({'background-color':'#DFD8D1'});
});
```

The first `#` is part of the jQuery selector, the second is (I assume) part of the JSF code to get the correct id of that element. I can't guarantee there won't be parsing problems on the server-side (I have no experience with JSF), but I'd expect it to work.

Comment: Gives: Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: unsupported pseudo: dataTable

Answer (score 1):

Just use the `widgetVar` attribute in your `<p:inputText>` and call your component by using this id:

```html
<p:inputText id="commentInput" widgetVar="txtCommentInput" ... >

...

jQuery(document).ready(function() {
     txtCommentInput.blur(function() {
        $(this).css({'background-color':'#DFD8D1'});
     });
});
```

Only note, don't set the `id` and `widgetVar` attributes the same value: http://forum.primefaces.org/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=18830#p59600

Comment: Gives: Uncaught ReferenceError: txtCommentInput is not defined. I already added widgetVar property but doesn't work.

Comment: @ÖmerFarukAlmalı make sure to clean all caches in your browser and try again.

Comment: even brand new browser didn't make any difference.